# Probability that 2 of 702 corpse flowers will bloom on the same day

Tags: probability

Just saw the news that two corpse flowers bloomed in the Japanese Botanical garden on the same day, by sheer chance, and have pollinated 700 seeds. This nearly extinct flower now has a significantly better chance of survival. Out of sheer curiosity, I wonder what the likelihood is over the next 10 years that two of these flowers will bloom on the same day. Simplifications/assumptions:

1. All 702 flowers are mature and all could bloom at any time.
2. Corpse flowers bloom for one day every 7-10 years. For simplicity let's say every 10 years. So one flower has 0.00027397 probability of blooming on any day in a ten year period.

I know how to calculate the likelihood that any ONE flower will bloom on a particular day: 1 - (the probability that Flower1 will NOT bloom on a day * the probability that Flower2 will NOT bloom on a day * etc).

I'm stuck on how to calculate whether any TWO will bloom on the same day.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the distribution to be uniform over that period, nor would I expect them to be independent (though maybe?).

Comment: As Lulu says, I really wouldn't expect the probabilities to be independent. As an analogy, imagine a family tree, drawn separated out into rows of each generation. Even if the tree were drawn to the correct vertical scale depicting the times of its births, it should still have a similar pattern of rows of generations. Similarly, most of your siblings and cousins will be a similar age to you, especially the closer the relation, and you would all reach adulthood at a similar time. Reasonably, we can expect a similar pattern of generations and nonindependence from the flowers.

Answer (score 2):

On any given day, a flower blooms independently with probability $p = 0.0027397$. Call this event $A$, and if $A$ happens we set $X_i$ = 1, where $i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ flower. Then, we can view each day as a binomial distribution, as each trial (flower blooming) is independent with the same exact probability. Hence, $S \thicksim Bin(702, 0.0027397)$. We now want $\mathbb{P}(S = 2)$ (or $\mathbb{P}(S \geq 2)$* which I suspect is what you want since your formula for 1 flower blooming is $\mathbb{P}(S \geq 1) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(S = 0)$), for which you can find the binomial probability mass function and calculate yourself.
If you wanted the probability of this happening sometime within ten years, if $n$ is the number of days in ten years and $q$ is our probability from above, $$\mathbb{P}(\text{Two flowers bloom on the same day over a 10 year period}) = (1-q)^n$$
Of course, if we assume that a flower can only bloom once in a 10 year period, then, it is much more complex. But I don't believe your question is phrased in such a way that you want that answered, but you can feel free to correct me.

*As a note from above, $$\mathbb{P}(S \geq 2) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(S = 1) - \mathbb{P}(S = 0) = \\1 - ({702 \choose 1}(p)^1(1-p)^{702-1}) - ({702 \choose 0}(p)^0(1-p)^{702-0})$$ Where p is the probability any given plant would bloom on a specific day.

Comment: We have 702 flowers. On any given day, they all have the same probability of blooming. $S$ is then a binomial that tells us how many flowers bloom on any given day, and $\mathbb{P}(S=2)$ is two plants blooming on one day. I don't know anything about plants, but based on the assumptions the problem made for simplicity, outside of the idea that maybe one can bloom twice in a ten year period, I don't know based on the problems wording. Otherwise, $S \thicksim Bin(702- \text{Number of bloomed flowers}, p)$, since a flower cant bloom twice.